# How to limit the memory size of the instance of EKS fargate

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I tried to limit the memory of my pod

```
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 2000m
          memory: 100Mi
        limits:
          cpu: 2000m
          memory: 140Mi
```

However, if I use `kubectl describe nodes` I still get allocated a 2vCPU, 16G memory node.

Comment: where are you limiting that? is this snipped part of which AWS API call?

Comment: It's in my deployment file for the pod

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the value of memory is invalid. From the AWS documentation `Fargate rounds up to the compute configuration shown below that most closely matches the sum of vCPU and memory requests in order to ensure pods always have the resources that they need to run.` ([reference here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate-pod-configuration.html))

You are defining a 2 vCPU with 140 Mebibyte of memory, that are way less that the 4GB minimum for that level of CPUs (4G = 3817Mi, you can run [conversion here](https://www.gbmb.org/mib-to-mb))

I personally expect, reading AWS configuration, that a pod with 2 vCPUs and 4GB of RAM is set in place. But maybe the 140Mi is considered invalid and it's round up to the maximum value for that range.

Maybe you were meaning 14000Mi (so 14.6 Gigabytes) of RAM?

Comment: Since I set the memory to be 140M, so it is expected to round up to the closest match, which is a 2vCPU, 4G memory fargate instance, however it always gives me the instance with the largest memory( in this case 16G) not matter how much I lower my memory request. In my case I just want a fargate instance with the lowest memory possible since my tasks are computational-intensive, not memory and I don't want to pay for the extra memory I don't even request for.

Comment: yes, that's what I was saying. I expect it to be 4G. Have you tried running with '4G' instead of 140mi, as less that 4G it's not an acceptable value for the system?

Comment: I will do my best to try and simulate this issue tomorrow. I can just suggest this read https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/monitoring-amazon-eks-on-aws-fargate-using-prometheus-and-grafana/  (first part) where there are some suggestions on how to track realy memory usage with Fargate. But maybe it's what you're doing already

Comment: Thank you for your help. I try to see the advisor metrics and I don't see any other pod consuming the memory other than my pod

Comment: Today I tested a similar solution and same for me, 16G instead of 4G. I tried with 6G and it was keeping 16G. I think we should raise a technical question to AWS team, at this point ...

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The output of `kubectl describe nodes` is not what counts in this case.

AWS sets an annotation "CapacityProvisioned" to the pod which describes the used instance size. The annotations are displayed in the UI Console under your cluster, Workloads, then Pods on the bottom right.

It is possible a node larger than requested is used, however, you are still limited to the requested resources.

Source: https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/942#issuecomment-747416514